# Saying Asher Yatzar if there is no water available

Tags: halacha, water, asher-yatzar

Suppose after using the facilities there is no water available, should one say Asher Yatzar without washing their hands?

Comment: Sounds like some poorly equipped facilities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, one should say Asher Yatzar even if he did not wash his hands. And if one was mishafshef, meaning he wiped the sprinkles of urine, he is required to clean his hands, even still, when there is no water he can wipe them on any surface that will clean them. [Shulchan Aruch siman 7](http://sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.7) siff 2 with [Mishna Berurah](http://sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.7) s.k. 5.